# User input must be 5 - 15 characters long and must not contain 'a'

Tags: java

I am creating a program where the user enters a string 5 - 15 characters long and must not contain the letter 'a.' I cannot figure out how to do it and what the problem with the code below is. Any suggestions regarding what I can do?

```
// STRING BETWEEN 5 - 15 CHARACTERS, MUST NOT CONTAIN LETTER 'a'

String lengthA;

System.out.println("Enter a string that is 5 - 15 characters long without using the letter 'a', 'A': ");



while(true) {

  lengthA = keyboard.nextLine();
  
  if (lengthA.length() < 5 - 15 && lengthA.contains("a", "A")) {
    System.out.println("Try again");
  } else {
    System.out.println("Congratulations! You have passed!");
    break;
  }
}
```

UPDATE: I have tried the codes that were suggested, however, all of them only check if the string contains the letter 'a'. It does not check for the length requirement. Any way to make sure that both the length and no 'a' requirement is there? Please and thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you think the requirement `5 - 15 characters long` means?

Comment: `lengthA.length() < 5 - 15`  is the same `lengthA.length() < -10` (the `-`operator has higher precedence than `<`; and `-` does NOT mean a range but just subtraction])

Comment: @tgdavies
When the user inputs a string, it cannot be below 5 characters nor higher than 15 characters.

Comment: *"... it cannot be below 5 characters nor higher than 15 characters"*.  So why did you compare the length of the string against `5 - 15 == 10`?  The point is ... you need to implement what the problem requirements **actually mean** ... not just copy the character of the requirement statement into your code.  The `-` in the requirements mean "between".  But in Java the operator `-` means "subtract".

Comment: You need to show what your new code is.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 if ( lengthA.length()< 5 || lengthA.length()>15 || lengthA.toLowerCase().contains("a")) {
  System.out.println("Try again");
}
```

`contains` can take only 1 parameter thus `lengthA.contains("a", "A")` its invalid. By converting the input in either **lowercase** or **uppercase** you can simply check whether the input `contains` your mentioned character sequences or not.

Think logically what you want and implement them one after another. Your conditioning logic is also wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant to Sayan post

Update the condition to check the length is between 5 and 15 and if the string contains one or more `a` or `A` using `Regex`

```
if (lengthA.length() < 5 || lengthA.length() > 15 || lengthA.matches("[aA]+")) {
    System.out.println("Try again");
} else {
   System.out.println("Congratulations! You have passed!");
   break;
}
```